# android: custom view xml onclick attribute try to find handler from view class instead of activity

Tags: android, xml, layout, onclick, android-custom-view

I create a custom view class and add it to my activity layout with onClick attribute in layout.xml. However, it throws exception when I click it.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method  
hack(SatelliteHackActivity)(View) in the activity class  
android.support.v7.widget.TintContextWrapper for onClick handler on view class 
dot.satellitehack.SatelliteView with id 'satellite'
```

Here are my code fragments.

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_satellite_hack"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="dot.satellitehack.SatelliteHackActivity" >
//...
    <dot.satellitehack.SatelliteView
        android:id="@+id/satellite"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:onClick="hack(SatelliteHackActivity)" />
//...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity.java

```
public class SatelliteHackActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void hack(View view) {
        //...
    }
}
```

CustomView.java

```
package dot.satellitehack;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class SatelliteView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {
    public static final int[] satelliteDrawables = new int[]{
        R.drawable.satellite01,
        R.drawable.satellite02,
        R.drawable.satellite03,
        R.drawable.satellite04,
        R.drawable.satellite05,
        R.drawable.satellite06,
        R.drawable.satellite07
    };

    public SatelliteView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SatelliteView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public SatelliteView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    protected void init() {
        if (null == getDrawable()) {
            setImageResource(satelliteDrawables[MathTools.random.nextInt(
                    satelliteDrawables.length
            )]);
        }
        setEnabled(false);
        setVisibility(GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        super.setEnabled(enabled);
        if (enabled) {
        setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }else {
            setVisibility(GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried android:onClick="hack(SatelliteHackActivity)" or "hack" which makes no differences.
Programmatically use setOnClickListener with hack(null) works well but I prefer adding onClick listener in xml. Could someone help me find out the reason of the error?

PS. I test it on Android 5.0

Comment: `android:onClick="hack(SatelliteHackActivity)"` has never been proper syntax. `android:onClick="hack"` should work, though Android seems to be looking for `hack()` on `android.support.v7.widget.TintContextWrapper` and not your activity.